# Laptop (Dell XPS) sometimes sleeps, sometimes hibernates?

Tags: laptop, sleep, hibernate

I have a Dell XPS 13 laptop which I have configured to sleep when the lid is closed. This normally works, however it appears sometimes it hibernates. At least, I think it hibernates, because it goes through the boot procedure. On the other hand, when I wake it from sleep the lock screen immediately appears.

I think this happens when I left the laptop sleeping for a longer period (10+ hours). Battery is nearly full.

Could someone shed some light on what could be happening here?

Answer (score 2):

Check your advanced power options, perhaps the hibernate after option is enabled which will cause your laptop to wake from sleep to hibernate

The wording sometimes differs between windows versions but to get to the advanced power settings dialog box either search or run "powercfg.cpl" -> Click "Change plan settings" on the currently selected power plan -> Click "Change advanced settings".

[image: advanced power options]

Comment: Thanks, but it set to Never for both "On battery" and "Plugged in".